# Start Java Platform from C#

Tags: c#, java

I have a windows application that uses WebBrowser in wich users can watch some flash animations and java applets.

I would like to start java platform on aplication start (even the user is not needing it), so user is not waiting for the platform to start, when he wants to look at the applets.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just have your WebBrowser control open a page with an applet upon application start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this would be possible. The Java VM is started by Internet Explorer when the Applet is loaded and IMHO you cannot modify this from the WebBrowser control.